# Loop over code over 10 iterations and save output in dataframe

Tags: r

I have some code below that I would like to loop over for 10 iterations. Every time I try a `for` loop, each iteration keeps getting overwritten.

Here is my sample dataframe:

```
> dput(covariate_matrix)
structure(list(id = 1:10, Age..Scaled. = c(0.95, -0.09, -2.34, 
0.55, 0.13, -1.34, 0.67, 0.99, -0.83, 0.34), Exposure = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Disease = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Comorbidity1 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Comorbidity2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Comorbidity3 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

and here is my clustering/logistic regression code that I would like to be looped over for 10 iterations, with each iteration's output being saved.

```
# In each iteration

cluster_algo <- kmeans(covariate_matrix, centers = 3)

#fit(cluster_algo, covariate_matrix)
cluster_label_assignments <- cluster_algo$cluster
cluster_label_assignments <-
  as.data.frame(cluster_label_assignments)
cluster_label_assignments <-
  cbind(cluster_label_assignments, covariate_matrix$id)
colnames(cluster_label_assignments)[2] <- "id"

cluster_labels <-
  unique(cluster_label_assignments[["cluster_label_assignments"]])

# Calculate OR
cluster_odds_ratios <- vector("numeric", 3)
for (c in seq_along(cluster_labels)) {
  within_label_individuals <- cluster_label_assignments %>%
    filter(cluster_label_assignments == c)
  or_calc_df <- covariate_matrix %>%
    filter(id %in% within_label_individuals[["id"]])
  cluster_fit <-
    glm(Disease ~ Exposure, data = or_calc_df, family = "binomial")
  cluster_or <- exp(coef(cluster_fit))
  cluster_odds_ratios[[c]] <- round(cluster_or[2], 4)
}

# Assign OR to individuals
cluster_odds_ratios_df <-
  data.frame(cluster_label_assignments = cluster_labels, or = cluster_odds_ratios)


individual_ors <-
  merge(cluster_label_assignments,
        cluster_odds_ratios_df,
        on = "cluster_label_assignments",
        how = "inner")
```

Currently, each iteration's output is being saved in the `individual_ors` dataframe. I would like this dataframe though to include ALL iterations' outputs.

Also, I know the odds ratios are janky, and that is because this is only a test dataset. Hopefully that doesn't matter too much in this toy example

Comment: Do you have 10 different `covariate_matrix`'s?

Comment: @RuiBarradas No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap a function around your code and call `replicate`. Then `rbind` the results list.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
})

# In each iteration

f <- function() {
  cluster_algo <- kmeans(covariate_matrix, centers = 3)
  
  #fit(cluster_algo, covariate_matrix)
  cluster_label_assignments <- cluster_algo$cluster
  cluster_label_assignments <-
    as.data.frame(cluster_label_assignments)
  cluster_label_assignments <-
    cbind(cluster_label_assignments, covariate_matrix$id)
  colnames(cluster_label_assignments)[2] <- "id"
  
  cluster_labels <-
    unique(cluster_label_assignments[["cluster_label_assignments"]])
  
  # Calculate OR
  cluster_odds_ratios <- vector("numeric", 3)
  for (c in seq_along(cluster_labels)) {
    within_label_individuals <- cluster_label_assignments %>%
      filter(cluster_label_assignments == c)
    or_calc_df <- covariate_matrix %>%
      filter(id %in% within_label_individuals[["id"]])
    cluster_fit <-
      glm(Disease ~ Exposure, data = or_calc_df, family = "binomial")
    cluster_or <- exp(coef(cluster_fit))
    cluster_odds_ratios[[c]] <- round(cluster_or[2], 4)
  }
  
  # Assign OR to individuals
  cluster_odds_ratios_df <-
    data.frame(cluster_label_assignments = cluster_labels, or = cluster_odds_ratios)
  
  individual_ors <-
    merge(cluster_label_assignments,
          cluster_odds_ratios_df,
          on = "cluster_label_assignments",
          how = "inner")
  individual_ors
}

# This is the loop the question asks for
res_list <- replicate(10, f(), simplify = FALSE)
all_ors <- do.call(rbind, res_list)

str(all_ors)
#> 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ cluster_label_assignments: int  1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 ...
#>  $ id                       : int  5 6 7 1 2 3 4 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ or                       : num  0 0 0 NA NA NA NA 0 0 0 ...

head(all_ors)
#>   cluster_label_assignments id or
#> 1                         1  5  0
#> 2                         1  6  0
#> 3                         1  7  0
#> 4                         2  1 NA
#> 5                         2  2 NA
#> 6                         2  3 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can `bind_rows` on each iteration. First add an empty dataframe *before* the loop starts:

```
final_ors = data.frame()
```

Then inside the loop you bind each of the `individual_ors` dataframe to it:

```
individual_ors <-
  merge(cluster_label_assignments,
        cluster_odds_ratios_df,
        on = "cluster_label_assignments",
        how = "inner")

final_ors = bind_rows(final_ors, individual_ors)
```

This way it gets bigger in each iteration while you replace the `individual_ors` object

Comment: Is it possible to modify the code to make it do 10 loops? Instead of me manually doing it?